# How to Refer to a Named Cell in a Relative Way in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 types of cell that I need to access via code. both are named cells. one is a cell with fixed column and row like ($B$3). I can access it in the code using its name => Range("Montante"). NO PROBLEM so far. the problem is when I try to access the other cell called "LEntrada" with fixed column but not fixed row like ($C8). Is there any way to access LEntrada according to the cell that the function is placed?

thanks in advance.

```
Public Function QtdEntradaSimulado3() As Variant
    On Error GoTo TratarErro
    Dim qtdEntrada As Integer
    Dim Montante As Range
    Dim LEntrada As Range

    Application.Volatile True

    Set Montante = Range("Montante")
    Set LEntrada = Range("LEntrada")

    qtdEntrada = Fix((Montante / LEntrada) / 100) * 100
    QtdEntradaSimulado3 = IIf(qtdEntrada = 0, "", qtdEntrada)

Sair:
    Exit Function
TratarErro:
    QtdEntradaSimulado3 = ""
    GoTo Sair
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Range() object doesn't look at the active cell to determine what a named range should refer to, but the Names() collection does. You can use it as follows:

```
    Set LEntrada = Names("LEntrada").RefersToRange
```

or if LEntrada was defined as a Double:

```
    LEntrada = Names("LEntrada").RefersToRange.Value
```